# Are there restrictions on NSUserDefault suite names?

Tags: ios, macos, nsuserdefaults, foundation

Are there any restrictions (length, invalid characters, etc.) on NSUserDefault suite names?

I'm thinking about using a server URL path as a suite name

Comment: why not regular UserDefault ?

Comment: our app is objective-c, they interface with the same foundation code so the same question applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) suggests that a domain name is expected.  It may be that characters outside of those allowed in a domain will work, but [given the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1410294-addsuite) explicitly specifies **domain name** I think it would be wise to adhere to that.